# RPC trips separate GFCI circuits on start up. Why?

Tags: gfci, motor

I have four 20A GFCI breakers each handling a string of outlets on each wall in my garage shop.  I also have an 100A circuit for a 20HP RPC (Rotary Phase Converter).  When I start the RPC it trips two and sometimes three of the GFCI circuit breakers. I can reset them and they are fine after that.  What's going on?

Comment: Is the 20hp on a soft start or inverter drive? If so in startup high harmonics end up on the ground / neutral and can cause all kinds of crazy problems like this . I add line reactors in the case of harmonics on the line side to dampen the harmonics there are also RFI filters that take the noise to ground but these only work with a good ground.

Comment: I don't know enough to answer.  My RPC is from North American:  Here is what it says: Control Panel
NEMA 1 Enclosure (Indoor)
Built-in Motor Starter
Digitally Controlled and Protected Start Circuit
ABB/Baldor Idler Generator Motor
ODP (Open Drip Proof) – Indoor Rated
Soft Start

I changed out one of the GFCI breakers and it doesn't trip, and the two others generally don't, although still do occasionally.

Comment: What make and model are the GFCI breakers in question? How is the B (generated, synthetic, ...) phase from the RPC handled -- is there a separate panel for the three phase loads, or are the single phase and three phase loads in the same panel?  Also, can you post photos of the panel that has the GFCI breakers in it?

Comment: Seimens.  Don't know what you mean by the B question, sorry. Here is more info on the RPC  https://www.northamericaphaseconverters.com/product/pro-line-rotary-phase-converter-pl-20/   I take 100A from the panel to the RPC.  All the 3 phase loads are separate.  The output from the three phase runs to a 3p 30A fused disconnect, and from there runs to a A/B knife switch.  A goes to my 5HP Quincy 325 Air Compressor, B will go to the rest of my woodworking machines.  Only wired to A so far. All 3 phase loads in or will be in surface mounted EMT conduit. Let me go take some pics.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/brD4Lji5GMFNk6hK8

Comment: @George -- is that panel your main panel or a subpanel, and if it's a subpanel, then how many wires are in the feed coming into it?

Comment: Main Panel.  I have dedicated 200A service to my garage.

Answer (score 1):

George that is a soft start. This is a way to reduce the current on start up the common way is twin SCR’s that are pulsed on until the motor is at speed. This creates a large amount of harmonics that end up on the neutral and even the ground circuits. If you look at my original comment I thought that might be the case. Line reactors on the incoming line may be the best in this case, however RFI filters on the line side may also work but a good ground reference is needed for RFI filters , I have seen harmonics cause 20+ volts on the neutral and 13+ volts on grounds and this affects other circuits like you are experiencing. One way to see if this is the problem is to monitor the neutral to ground voltage when you start the system.  More than 2.5 volts in my experience not only causes GFCI problems but can cause switching power supplies like in computers and many lighting circuits to malfunction because the reference voltage is shifted. We see this in industrial facilities quite often and use line reactors mostly. 20 hp in a home based system is more than 2x anything I have ever seen and 4x normal homes in my experience.

Edit : whoops I thought it was 20 Hp not 20 amps. Still similar issues but a 1-2 hp motor may be able to be soft started without a line reactor but RFI filters may be the best option. I would suggest checking your homes grounding electrode system. Not that many years back a single water pipe feeding the home was totally code legal but with updates to plastic pipe some of these homes end up with insufficient grounds and the reason multiple grounding electrodes required today or supplemental ones.

Comment: Ed, the idler moor is 20HP.   I have vintage machinery. All have 3 phase motors.  The 200A dedicated service to my shop is new, and has the standard two grounding rods.

Comment: Ok I rescanned the question after answering but believe the issue is harmonics on the neutral /ground  20 hp is a large load for a residential service. A line reactor on the line side may help.